# How to replace all timestamps to date in a single string in PHP?

Tags: php

i need to replace all timestamps into a date but they're all in the same string and the output needs to be in the same string, i tried different methods but i can't get it working

The string format is like this one:

```
timestamp=1615676829306\sinvoker_database_id=1\sinvoker_nickname=serveradmin1\saction=query-join\sip=0.0.0.0\susername=serveradmin\sother_server=1\ssid=530|timestamp=1615676820366\sinvoker_database_id=32281\sinvoker_nickname=Electronic\sBot\saction=channel-edit\schannel_id=150\sproperty=channel_name\svalue_old=[cspacer]⠀⠀⠀█⠀▄⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀▄⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀\svalue_new=[cspacer]⠀⠀⠀█⠀▄⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀▄⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀▄▀⠀⠀|
```

The output should be like

```
timestamp=2021-03-13-22:04\sinvoker_database_id=1\sinvoker_nickname=serveradmin1\saction=query-join\sip=0.0.0.0\susername=serveradmin\sother_server=1\ssid=530|timestamp=2021-03-13-22:05\sinvoker_database_id=32281\sinvoker_nickname=Electronic\sBot\saction=channel-edit\schannel_id=150\sproperty=channel_name\svalue_old=[cspacer]⠀⠀⠀█⠀▄⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀▄⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀\svalue_new=[cspacer]⠀⠀⠀█⠀▄⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀▄⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀▄▀⠀⠀|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[preg_replace_callback()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) will do the job for you.

```
$str = 'timestamp=1615676829306\sinvoker_database_id=1\sinvoker_nickname=serveradmin1\saction=query-join\sip=0.0.0.0\susername=serveradmin\sother_server=1\ssid=530|timestamp=1615676820366\sinvoker_database_id=32281\sinvoker_nickname=Electronic\sBot\saction=channel-edit\schannel_id=150\sproperty=channel_name\svalue_old=[cspacer]⠀⠀⠀█⠀▄⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀▄⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀\svalue_new=[cspacer]⠀⠀⠀█⠀▄⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀▄⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀▄▀⠀⠀|';

// the regex searches for and captures 'timestamp=' and a 13-digit numeric field
// These are passed to the callback function, and the return value is used to 
// replace the original text

$newStr = preg_replace_callback('/(timestamp=)(\d{13})/', function($a) {

    // Convert the 13 digits string to an integer, and divide by 0
    // to drop the milliseconds. Then use date() to produce the required format
    return $a[1].date('Y-m-d-H:i', floor((int)$a[2] / 1000));

}, $str);

// timestamp=2021-03-14-12:07\sinvoker_database_id=1\sinvoker_nickname=serveradmin1\saction=query-join\sip=0.0.0.0\susername=serveradmin\sother_server=1\ssid=530|timestamp=2021-03-14-12:07\sinvoker_database_id=32281\sinvoker_nickname=Electronic\sBot\saction=channel-edit\schannel_id=150\sproperty=channel_name\svalue_old=[cspacer]⠀⠀⠀█⠀▄⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀▄⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀\svalue_new=[cspacer]⠀⠀⠀█⠀▄⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀▄⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀█⠀⠀⠀▄▀⠀⠀|
echo $newStr;
```